# creating user sitemap

Tags: web-services, sitemap

I have got a web site, I need to create a sitemap for users, I mean just creating a page, say sitemap.jsp and create a text link to each page? 
is there any useful tool to get all the link, instead of having to put the links manually?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Two options are A1 Sitemap Generator (commercial) or GSiteCrawler (free) - you could also search on the net for more alternatives (there are many!)